# linq .ToList() return all the record ignores the where clause?

Tags: c#, linq

the below linq query shows me all the result set, instead of filtering it with where clause premalink.PremalinkID == id???

```
 lstpremalink = dalpremalink.GetUserNewsFeed(UserID);
 var premalinkid = (from p in lstpremalink select p.PremalinkID).Distinct();

    foreach (Int64 id in premalinkid)
    {
   lstprema = (from premalinktags in lstpremalink
                   where premalinktags.PremalinkID == id
                   select premalinktags).ToList(); 
}
```

lstprema  shows all the result set below

[image]

Comment: are you sure this compiles at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lstprema = (from premalinktags in lstpremalink 
            where premalink.PremalinkID == id select premalinktags).ToList();
```

You iterate by `premalinktags` but your `where` clause does not contain that variable! Shouldn't it be `premalinktags.PremalinkID == id` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
 lstpremalink = dalpremalink.GetUserNewsFeed(UserID);

 var premalinkid = (from p in lstpremalink 
                    where p.PremalinkID == lstpremaLink.ID 
                    select p).Distinct();
```

You must use a where condition

Comment: '(from p in lstpremalink where p.PremalinkID == lstpremaLink.ID select p.PremalinkID)' isn't this like saying "give me everything where '4 == 4', and then return '4' .. ?

Comment: haha yah David Johnson i just started learning linq two hours ago :) i am making progress but i would say sorry to all the gurus i am going to offend by my question

Comment: Trust me, you're not that far off from me. Here is a resource that really has helped me in my career. Well worth the money. Great section on LINQ too. http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=linq-fundamentals&highlight=scott-allen_linq-introduction*6,8,11,2,12,13!scott-allen_linq-queries!scott-allen_linq-csharp*1,10!scott-allen_linq-operators#linq-introduction